# Multi store view stuck?

Tags: magento2, multistore, tax, geoip

So I want to have a multi store view.

1. UK/Europe - Inclusive of 20% vat tax
2. International - Exclude 20% vat tax.

I have an Amasty geoip also installed so maybe I can use that for the auto detect? but I want the option to manually override

i.e if the user is in the USA but wants to view the UK store they can. Id like to also have certain shipping rules for the selected countries and also show country icons and I can accept £,$ and EUR in terms of checkout so this must have a switcher.

How can I set up this switch? and will it save the basket?

for example, this site has it: https://goo.gl/hU79Rw

[image]

Comment: If anyone can guide what can and cant be done... direction, cost guide and best method of practice as i am getting mixed answers from developers on freelancer... if anyone has a solution, happy to pay for it. i.e. extension or a bespoke solution

Answer (score 0):

Below are the things you can consider

- You have to created 2 Stores 1 for UK/Europe & 1 for International
- UK Store only accepts only GBP, whilge International Store accepts
  $, EURO, etc..
- When you switch store from one to another it will remove/empty cart.
- So on basis of IP you can redirect UK users to UK store & others to International
- For Shipping you can use Magento Default "Table Rates" Shipping Module
- For Sharing Shopping cart you can follow below links

http://www.magestore.com/magento/magento-multiple-websites-share-shopping-cart.html/

[Share cart in magento 2 multistore](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126658/share-cart-in-magento-2-multistore)