# Magento 2: Add to Cart and Cart Sharing do not work on multi store setup

Tags: magento2, cart, multistore, multidomain

I am trying to setup a multi store website with shared cart. I followed the instruction on this article: [Share cart in magento 2 multistore](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126658/share-cart-in-magento-2-multistore)

However, I noticed that sharing cart functionality does not work. I am only able to add items to the cart for the default store.

I will outline the key steps below.

**Created multiple Stores**

I have setup 3 Stores with 1 Website. Each Store has its unique Store View.

One thing ambiguous about this article was that what to do with the `Default Store View`. I changed `Store Code` for the "Default Store View" from "default" to "store1". And renamed it from "Default Store View" to "Store View 1".

I set `Store Code` for the 2nd Store as "store2", and same for 3rd Store as "store3".

[image]

**Root Categories for each store**

I used the `Default Category` as the root category for store1.

I created Store2 Root Category for store2.

I created Store3 Root Category for store3.

[image]

**Share cart admin setting**

Since I wanted to share the cart among 3 Stores, I had to set `Share Customer Accounts` as "Global" for the Default Config.

[image]

**Domain names**

I created virtual hosts for the default domain as "dev.m2.com".

The 2nd store domain is "dev.m2b.com".

The 3rd store domain is "dev.m2c.com".

**.htaccess change**

I added this code to `.htaccess` file on the project root:

```
SetEnvIf Host dev.m2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store1
SetEnvIf Host dev.m2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^dev.m2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store1
SetEnvIf Host ^dev.m2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host dev.m2b.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store2
SetEnvIf Host dev.m2b.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^dev.m2b.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store2
SetEnvIf Host ^dev.m2b.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host dev.m2c.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store3
SetEnvIf Host dev.m2c.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^dev.m2c.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store3
SetEnvIf Host ^dev.m2c.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

**index.php change**

`Store Switcher` worked fine from switching from store1 to store2, and from store1 to store3, and from store2 to store3. However, switching back from store2/3 to store1 required to use the Store Switcher twice to go back to store1.

Due to this, I had to reset the value for `$_COOKIE['store']` at the `index.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

// Fix store switcher bug on switching to the default store
if ( isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) == 'store' && isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ) {
    if ( !empty($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ) {
        $_COOKIE['store'] = $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'];
    }
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**.htaccess change (2nd time)**

On the browser's inspector, a lot of `CORS` error was reported. To remove this, I added this code to `.htaccess`:

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

**Add to Cart on store2 and store3 do not work**

Now at this point, the Store Switcher is working correctly. But, the `Add to Cart` button is not working on store2 and store3.

I can add items on the store1 (the default store), and it would update the mini cart. But, if I switched to store2 or store3, the cart is empty. And when I try to add an item to the cart, I get one of the following scenarios:

1: The `Add to Cart` button on store2 and store3 stays on "Adding....", and nothing added to the cart. No JavaScript errors.

[image]

2: The `Add to Cart` button on store2 and store3 changes from "Adding..." to "Added", but the cart is not updated. No JavaScript errors.

[image]

Note, this happens for both logged-in and not-logged-in users.

**Summary**

How can I make the cart be shared among the 3 Stores for logged-in users?

Is it possible to make it work for not-logged-in users?

Having 3 different root categories for each store be part of the issue? Do I have to have a category shared among multiple Stores?

**More info**

I tried `Add Store Code to Urls` to Yes, but it did not solve the problem.

The `Add to Cart` AJAX call on the store2 resulted in "You have no items in your shopping cart." page, rendered from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/noItems.phtml` It seems store2 cannot find items in the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Add to Cart` buttons started to work when I performed these 2 tasks from command line:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

For a reference, I set the `Cookie Path` to be `/` for all Stores as follows:

[image]
[image]

I did not change Cookie settings and am using default for `Default Config` and `Main Website`. The `Cookie Path` is set for Store View 1, Store View 2, and Store View 3.

Comment: Also if still you getting issue then please verify cookie domain if mentioned there in every store

Comment: Hi @Yas Nakano, when I am switching from one to another store cart is going to empty. I have disabled all the custom & 3rd party modules and verified but no luck. Version 2.3.5 EE I am using.   could you please advise