# Magento2 : Product added to cart multi stores

Tags: product, cart, magento-2.1, multistore

In my sites having two stores A and B, I created stores using **symlinks**.

When I have added products to the cart in B store it added but at the same time products added to mini cart in A store as well.

Why it is showing like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **Sessions**

When you setup multistore in Magento 2, don't symlink 'var/sessions' folder.

For more information, you may interested in [how to share cart in Magento 2 multiple store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126658/share-cart-in-magento-2-multistore).

Comment: i didnt created symlink to seesion , i dont want share cart  @Toan Nguyen

Comment: @Nadh: That's why I reference to that question. To let you check all steps to make cart sharing in Magento 2 multiple store, then you can compare it to your own to avoid cart sharing.