# Magento 2 best architecture for a multi country side

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento-2.1.1

We are developing a hybrid app where the front end is react native and the backend is magento 2.1.4 and the frontend and backend are communicating via REST APIs

The offering is across 3 countries. Starting with country A then B then C. each country might have different payment gateways to support them. For instance payment gateways X might work for country A and B but not C.

Now also each country might have different shipping rules. For instance we might limit shipping in country A to just 2 cities in it. Country B we might ship to all cities. We might offer free shipping in country A but for country B and C offer free shipping for orders above $100.

Lastly , some products will only be sold in country A and not B and C.

We want users to be able to move between countries.

The question is that can this setup work with one website , 3 stores per country , and two language storefronts per store, or do I have to create a website for each country to meet the needs listed above?

Thanks for engaging with this question.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

there based on your description I think that you will need more than one website. Check this question and the answer: [Difference between website, stores and store views](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7393/difference-between-website-stores-and-store-views)

As the guy said:

If you want to sell your products in several stores and have to change one of the following criteria in these shops, then you have to go for different websites:

1. different prices
2. different tax classes
3. different (base) currencies
4. different payment options
5. different shipping options

And you said that you want different payment for at least one of the shop, then you will need to create website for this shop.
As I understand it, create website for A,B,C create store view for every website. If the products are the same you can use one root category for all stores, and create store view for every language that you need for every store view.

It is up to you to decide do you want to share users between different web sites, so they can login everywhere with one account or not.

Comment: Thanks Nikola for your answer. So if I have three different websites can I share the users between them ? Can I user live across 3 websites.

Comment: Also. Just to sup up what you saying : have 3 different websites , 3 different stores ( each website has its corresponding store) and for each store have the store views based on the language service offering ?

Comment: Yes, you can share users between different websites, you need to setup this correctly.
For you second question, I think that is the setup that you need, based on what you explain in the question.

Comment: Hello Nikola, when you say for users to cross multiple websites that that needs to setup correctly. Is that done in the admin console ? Or in special code. For instance is there suck a setting that says when users are created (we will be creating them via the REST API from the front end ). Create users across all websites in this instance.

Comment: Yes it is done admin console, it is an option.

Comment: Hello Nikola, I could not find where I can set that up in the admin console. I see under the customers tab you have a drop down to switch the users between website A , B , or C. But where do you setup that you want a customer  to belong to A B and C

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126658/share-cart-in-magento-2-multistore