# Share Cart in Multi Website Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multi-website

I have a setup a multi website.
https://domainname.com and https://demo.domainname.com

I need to share cart items between each website.
So if i have added a cart items to A website and if i login to B website than it must be found there as well.

I have set `Share Customer Account = Global` in `Stores->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Account Sharing Options`

Please help me to sort out this issue.

I am using Magento 2.2.6

Comment: did you follow this [one?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/130581/55928) find [Reff](http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/08/share-cart-magento-2-multistore-website.html)

Comment: @Hit's, yes i have tried that but its not working.

Comment: Hi Sanjay Jethva, Did you got solution ???

Comment: @balu, still not found any solution

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @SanjayJethva did you find solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Different domains will be a pain. 
I would make a cudtum session di. Setup a third domain and store and embed on both with an iframe. Then you can have the module sync sessions between the two domains

I found to switch websites i used a custom site switcher. When you switch sites create a new cart for the other website and copy all items to it.

As an added bennie any product price or availability changes carry over with the recalc

Comment: Which site switcher?